# Shielding against 14 MeV instant neutron point source

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

In [this paper](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/supplement/Impact%20Fusion%20Write-Up.pdf) (as found [here](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php#id--Nukes_In_Space--Warhead--Chemical-Explosion_Thermonuclear)), an alternate type of fusion bomb design is proposed. This design, however, emits a cone of 14 MeV neutrons upon explosion - only a cone because the neutrons are absorbed by other components in the other directions. While this may be useful for a strategic weapon, it may be a drawback for other uses, such as nuclear pulse propulsion. Even as a weapon, it may not be desirable to activate exposed material.

What would be the best way to stop those neutrons? The most important factor is mass, followed by length of the device. It should also not be too expensive or impractical a material, so Xenon-135 is out, for example.

What I found so far suggests a Fe-56 layer to slow neutrons down to thermal energies, then B-10 to stop them. I am not sure how effective that would be, however, or what better designs could be possible.

Comment: Why is it a drawback for nuclear pulse propulsion?

Comment: Go to the National Nuclear Data Center at Brookhaven's website, and look at the cross section data provided there. Note that mass is not the most important factor.

Comment: Frankly in the immediate neighborhood of a fussion explosive you may have bigger problems that neutrons, and when you are far enough away for that to no longer be an issue you're not looking at collimated, hot neutrons anymore: they are going to be thermalized.

Comment: @Communisty You don't want to spew neutrons at your spacecraft, as this would cause neutron embrittlement and activation of your pusher plate. So you would have to point it away. Then, at launch you would spray the ground with neutrons, which may cause the same problems at and nearby the spaceport, and would drive environmentalists nuts. You don't want to use nukes near the Van Allen belt, but elsewhere, you would have to be careful not spraying neutrons at nearby spacecrafts and satellites. Many complications and risks, so it would be simpler to shield the pulse unit itself, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the title question *"Shielding against 14 MeV instant neutron point source"*, we start by noting that there is absolutely nothing unusual about shielding 14 MeV neutrons as that is the energy that comes from most commercially available neutron generators.<sup>1</sup>

You use a combination of moderators and absorbers with a supplementary gamma shield to deal with the absorption photons.

In the nuclear power industry borated-poly (i.e. plastic doped with boron) is a common choice for the moderator/absorber combination, because it is light; easily formed and machined; not terribly expensive; less of a fire hazard than waxes or oils; and easier to confine than liquids. Borated concrete is also used where better temperature resistance is needed and you can afford the weight.

Chlorine and gadolinium are also good absorbers and are used in places (notice that PVC automatically works as an moderator/absorber). Gadolinium used to be prohibitively expensive, but massive rare-earth refining operations in China have driven the price way down.

The gamma shield can be lead, iron, water, concrete or whatever depending on the space and engineering constraints.

---

<sup>1</sup> As a general matter neutron shielding is a pain in the rear, but it is well understood, and here you are proposing to worry about one of the most common energy regimes encountered in practical applications.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. While 14 MeV neutrons seem common in the industry, I couldn't find good details about it, particularly for a "flash" like from a nuke. Looking at borated-poly I found a paper comparing varied poly at a range of energies. It seems that at 14 MeV, pure poly is slightly more effective, and bismuth-poly is better by length (but heavier). It seems like much is needed. I found that you need 1 m of bismuth-poly to reduce neutron flux by 100. Still, it looks like a workable option.

Comment: As for gadolinium, I couldn't find any data about its 14 MeV cross-section. My search-fu is not the best, did I miss it? Otherwise, is it used with other materials to thermalize neutrons first? Are there good on-line resources where I can find more about that?

Comment: Almost all neutron capture cross-sections at non-trivial energy are strongly peaked. That's why you moderate. In other words you don't try to capture 14 MeV neutrons: you try to slow them down. The thing that controls moderator effectiveness is (to first order) the number of hydrogen atoms per unit volume (other low A nuclei also contribute). Water and paraffin were popular choices in the early days. Water still is because it is cheap and safe. Solid polymers has long since replaced waxes for safety and engineering reasons.

Comment: So the idea is to pack as much hydrogen as possible, and then add some boron or gadolinium to absorb them, which is why polyethylene is used today. Those hydrogen-storage nanomaterials promising 1000 kg/m³ could help in the future, if they work out. Any reason not to use iron, though? I found suggestions to put 7 or 10 cm of it before polyethylene to help thermalise neutrons.